# InvalidArgumentException: "\string$filter" is not a valid Fqsen with $objectManager->get()

Tags: php, exception, phpunit, typo3, typo3-10.x

Running the Unit-tests for the TYPO3 Crawler with TYPO3 10.2

```
TYPO3_PATH_WEB=$PWD/.Build/Web typo3DatabaseName=crawler typo3DatabaseHost=127.0.0.1 typo3DatabaseUsername=root typo3DatabasePassword=root .Build/bin/phpunit -c .Build/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/res/Configuration/FunctionalTests.xml Tests/Functional --filter canCreateQueueEntriesUsingConfigurationRecord
```

I get following error, see below.

If I change https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/blob/typo3v9/Classes/Api/CrawlerApi.php#L76
to `GeneralUtility::makeInstance()` it works, but with `$objectManager->get()` is doesn't work.

I know that the line can be removed completely, just wanted to understand what the problem is here. I don't find any logic in it.

To try it out your self you could adjust the require-dev section in composer.json to

```
    "require-dev": {
        "nimut/testing-framework": "^4.1 || dev-master",
        "nimut/typo3-complete": "^9.5 || ^10.2",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^0.11.19",
        "rector/rector": "^0.6",
        "symplify/easy-coding-standard": "^7.0"
    },
```

**ERROR**

```
There was 1 error:

1) AOE\Crawler\Tests\Functional\Api\CrawlerApiTest::canCreateQueueEntriesUsingConfigurationRecord
InvalidArgumentException: "\string$filter" is not a valid Fqsen!.

/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/vendor/phpdocumentor/reflection-common/src/Fqsen.php:48
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/src/FqsenResolver.php:70
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/src/FqsenResolver.php:32
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/src/TypeResolver.php:264
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/vendor/phpdocumentor/type-resolver/src/TypeResolver.php:118
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ClassSchema.php:401
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ClassSchema.php:185
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ReflectionService.php:112
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Reflection/ReflectionService.php:99
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/Container.php:158
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/Container.php:110
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/ObjectManager.php:126
/path/to/extension/crawler/Classes/Api/CrawlerApi.php:76
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php:3461
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/Container.php:193
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/Container.php:166
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/Container/Container.php:110
/path/to/extension/crawler/.Build/Web/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Object/ObjectManager.php:126
/path/to/extension/crawler/Tests/Functional/Api/CrawlerApiTest.php:116
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is most likely in `CrawelerController`. The `ObjectManager` analyzes the class that should be created and all dependent classes.

In this case there is a format error in a doc block:
https://github.com/AOEpeople/crawler/blob/typo3v9/Classes/Controller/CrawlerController.php#L940

```
/**
 * Return array of records from crawler queue for input page ID
 *
 * @param integer $id Page ID for which to look up log entries.
 * @param string$filter Filter: "all" => all entries, "pending" => all that is not yet run, "finished" => all complete ones
 * @param boolean $doFlush If TRUE, then entries selected at DELETED(!) instead of selected!
 * @param boolean $doFullFlush
 * @param integer $itemsPerPage Limit the amount of entries per page default is 10
 * @return array
 */
public function getLogEntriesForPageId($id, $filter = '', $doFlush = false, $doFullFlush = false, $itemsPerPage = 10)
```

There is a missing space between `string$filter`

Comment: That was exactly it.. Thanks, didn't even look into this file, Didn't find any indication that the problem was in that file from stack trace. 

Thanks.

Comment: True... Using xdebug and check what parameters were used when it fails makes things easier. However this one was rather easy to spot as it was directly in the class that should have been constructed.

Comment: I didn't think about looking into that class as I was focusing on the class in use itself. 

But thanks for your help, Will keep it in mind for the next time.